# How to add a CA root at Istio-Ingressgateway's list of trusted CAs?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, ca

I have a gateway, with TLS termination at the gateway using mode SIMPLE (see below snippet)

```yaml
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio's default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: https
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
      minProtocolVersion: TLSV1_2
      maxProtocolVersion: TLSV1_3
    hosts:
    - "*"
  - port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: http
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true
      minProtocolVersion: TLSV1_2
      maxProtocolVersion: TLSV1_3
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

I have a requirement where I need to be able to trust a specific root along with all the others I already am trusting (part of the list of ca-certificates of istio gateway). Keeping in mind, I cannot change the mode here to MUTUAL, is it possible to add the trusted root?

Comment: If you're asking if caCertificates will work with SIMPLE tls mode then AFAIK it won't. Maybe you could try to add add Plugging in existing CA Certificates as mentioned in istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/cert-management/plugin-ca-cert/)? Maybe you could try to add [destination rule](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ClientTLSSettings) for this specific host with tls mode mutual and caCertificates?